# When should I draw in a custom layout based on its size

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am creating a new `ViewGroup`. The new view will have some circles drawn in it. The view is supposed to have 5 initial circles in it so I want to spread them evenly across the width of the view, and also keep track of them (their center's (x,y) position) in order to redraw them when the view is invalidated.

This is my `onMeasure`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    int desiredWidth = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + PREFERED_SIZE;
    int desiredHeight = getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom() + PREFERED_SIZE;

    actualWidth = resolveSizeAndState(desiredWidth,widthMeasureSpec,0);
    actualHeight = resolveSizeAndState(desiredHeight,heightMeasureSpec,0);
    setMeasuredDimension(actualWidth, actualHeight);
}
```

What I'm not sure is when should I add these circles. `onMeasure` can be called several times and get a different width and height values so I'm not sure when should I calculate the (x,y) for the initial circles.. inside `onMeasure`? in the beginning of `onDraw`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check on the docs. There're 3 callbacks on the measurement part and I guess you can do on the last one: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

- `onMeasure(int, int)` Called to determine the size requirements for this view and all of its children.
- `onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int)`   Called when this view should assign a size and position to all of its children.
- `onSizeChanged(int, int, int, int)`   Called when the size of this view has changed.

So I guess the best for your calculations is `onSizeChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `View.OnLayoutChangeListener` to track the layout changes :

```
public class CustomView extends View implements View.OnLayoutChangeListener {

    private int height;
    private int width;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // add the layout listener
        addOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        height = getHeight();
        width = getWidth();
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems almost exactly like onMeasure?

Comment: Not exactly, `onMeasure` gets called more times than `onLayoutChange`. `onMeasure` is called every time the parent view needs to calculate the layout, while `onLayoutChange` gets called when the layout of the particular view changes.